# jQuery How to stopPropagation on touch move on a div and all its descendents

Tags: javascript, jquery

Sorry didn't really know how to word it. But I have a div in which I want all the elements in it to have a `.stopPropagation`. But I want to do it on `click` and touch events like `touchstart touchend touchmove tap dbltap dragstart dragmove dragend`

So I was thinking I could do this:

```
$('#div1').find('*').bind("click touchstart touchend touchmove tap dbltap dragstart dragmove dragend", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

But I'm not sure if this is the correct way of doing it. Maybe I need a `.each()`?

Also, I've never used the `'*'` to select all, so I'm not sure if it should be the way I have it or if it should be `.find(*)` without the single quotes.

Thanks!

Comment: Its correct , except that you need to use `.on()` instead of `.bind()` which is deprecated in latest version of jQuery lib

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `.find('*')`, if you want to stop the propagation from `div1` - if the event happens in an descendant it will propagate up till `div1` and then will stop there

```
$('#div1').on("click touchstart touchend touchmove tap dbltap dragstart dragmove dragend", function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Well there is bubbling happening in the div, so I want to stop all of it. If that makes sense

Comment: @John_911 do you want to stop the internal bubbling also?

Comment: @John_911 in that case you will have to use `$('#div1, #div1 *').on(...)`